# In the chrome extension, how to use the MPEG-DASH protocol to perform screen recording like loom?

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder, mpeg-dash, web-mediarecorder

In the browser, if I want to implement a screen recording function similar to loom, and record more than 5 hours of video, how to achieve it if I use HLS, I don’t know any ideas, does anyone know how loom is implemented?

I did a simple analysis of the loom extension, guessing that the implementation of loom is to cut the video into many fragments and upload them, but I don't know how to generate MPD files in the browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czh6r.png)
This is a screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSfyr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxtn5.png)

I have no idea, I don’t know how to use javascript to realize it, I hope I can give a reference link or demo

I am not familiar with media streaming, hope to give guidance

Answer (score -2):

If you're using react, this package makes it easy: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam

Should allow you to use webcam to capture media (screenshot / stream video) and save those chunks.

Nb: not sure it solves for the length of video or specific transport (HSL)

Comment: OP is asking for a solution to record the computer screen, not the webcam.

Comment: Indeed. I assumed that package would allow the full capture (screen, vid/audio, etc). I suppose the solution would be to lean on the [desktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/)

^^^ Not exactly sure what the limitations are there. See example implementation in this article: [Capture a MediaStream from a canvas, video or audio element](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/capture-stream/)

Comment: Check this video tut as well. Gives a quick overview of how to build a Loom-like clone: [Building a Loom like chrome extension with React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZt8VHa4mpM)